# Disabling optimization with QTCreator's debug mode

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to disable optimization in QTCreator to prevent `<optimized out>` values in debug mode
I added these in my `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O0
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -O1
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -O2
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -O3
```

and the compile is running with `-O0` switch:

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O0 `itpp-config --cflags-opt` -g -std=c++1y -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../ver.1-1.ryn -I. -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtPrintSupport -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtXml -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o main.o ../ver.1-1.ryn/main.cpp
```

But when i run program in debug mode I still see `<optimized out>` values and setping jumps over the lines!!

How can i correctly disable optimization in debug mode of QTCreator and solve the `<optimized out>` and jumping problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about your own code or some other library code? Are you sure `itpp-config --cflags` isn't returning -O2 or similar?

Comment: @peppe: I'm talking about my own code (which is using it++ library) ; yes!! you're  right!! Thanks!! `itpp-config --cflags` is returning `-I/usr/local/include -O3 -DNDEBUG` ; thank you very much; if you create an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check what `itpp-config --cflags` is returning. Probably it needs also a `--debug` option to avoid returning optimization flags.

Answer (score 1):

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O1
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O3
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O0

QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O1
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O3
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -O0
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are using the correct means to remove any pre-existing `-O` flags from the `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` as the qmake `mkspecs` files for the various build configuration/target system/build system/host system/compiler/cpu/number of bits/phase of moon options can alter such things as well.  What I have seen and done myself is:

```
CONFIG ~= s/-O[0123s]//g
CONFIG += -O0
```

the first line utilises a 'sed' like edit to change the variable at that point in processing which *I think* is triggered by the `~=` operator; in this usage it means a search {leading `s`} for any of the regular expression between the first and second `/` i.e. {`-O0` or `-O1` or `-O2` or `-O3` or `-Os`} which are replace by what is between the second and third `/` i.e. {nothing} and to do that globally {as per the trailing `g`, a positive number of times is likely to be possible as well}...

Some may argue that, if you are a project creator/maintainer, modifying what gets used for CFLAG / CXXFLAG is a no-no and it should be left to the end-user to adjust such a thing for themselves *as* the end-user.  That is however a *whole different metallic sealed container of Annelids*!